Is there an arbitrage ? (Solve question 1c)


How do we solve question 1 part c?

Hint:notice that the third asset is >= the 2nd asset in all scenarios.

Though the question is clear enough, it would be nice if you also cited the source in detail.

At time $t_0$

buy 1 unit of Asset 3 at $\\\$200$
short sell 2 units of Asset 2 at $\\\$200$ each receiving $\\\$200$
Our net cash flow at $t_0$ is $\\\$200$ (from short selling asset 2) - $\\\$200$ (from buying asset 3) $= 0$

At time $t_2$, we can calulate the net payoff in each state by considering the payoffs from asset 3 and the obligations from the short position in asset 2



State $(\omega)$
Asset 3 Value at $ t_2 $
Short Position in Asset 2 (2 units)
Net Payoff




$\omega_1$
\$360
$-2 \times \\\$180 = -\\\$360$
\$0


$\omega_2$
\$120
$-2 \times \\\$60 = -\\\$120$
\$0


$\omega_3$
\$260
$-2 \times \\\$126 = -\\\$252$
\$8


$\omega_4$
\$200
$-2 \times \\\$100 = -\\\$200$
\$0


$\omega_5$
\$150
$-2 \times \\\$72 = -\\\$144$
\$6



Notice, we have non-negative payoffs in all states, and positive payoffs in states $\omega_3$ and $\omega_5$.
Thus, this strategy yields riskless profit with zero initial investment. The presence of this strategy indicates that the market is not free of arbitrage opportunities when the third asset is included.
